# Undefined method `to_hash' while saving with reform gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, rubygems, reform

I got a problem. I'm using reform gem in my Rails application with some complex forms. Unfortunately I stuck while creating a form. That's my code:

```
class Order::Form < Reform::Form
  include Coercion
  include Composition
  include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord

  property :subscription, on: :order
  property :due_date, type: Date, on: :order
  property :start_fee, numericality: true, on: :order

  collection :products, populate_if_empty: Product, on: :order do
    property :type
    property :budget
  end

  property :campaign, on: :order do
    property :customer_id

    property :customer do
      property :id
      property :organization_number
    end
  end

  model :order

  def persist!(params)
    if validate(params)
      binding.pry
      # begin
        ::ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          save do |data, map|
            ...
          end
        end
      # rescue Exception
      #   false
      # end
    end
  end
end
```

And when I'm trying to save I recieve this error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `to_hash' for #<#<Class:0x007f984ddef6d8>:0x007f984a65a4>
```

I wonder if I correctly configured Composition with nested models.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same exception, and it happened because I was redefining one Constant (`ENV`) setting to be a `String`. Because originally it was a Global Constant type `Hash`, the gem I was using got confused.

Try to see if somewhere else you are replacing the value of something that used to be a Hash.